# Define `url_variables` for `Webhooks` in GitLab

Tags: gitlab

How do I define `url_variables` for `Webhooks` in GitLab?

The [Webhooks documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/16.7/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#mask-sensitive-portions-of-webhook-urls) says:

> To interpolate sensitive portions for each webhook, use `url_variables`.

and

> You can define URL variables directly using the REST API.

In the REST API documentation under [Get Project Hook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#get-project-hook) there is a `url_variables` key.

But I cannot find any `url_variables` neither in [Add Project Hook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#add-project-hook) nor in [Edit Project Hook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#edit-project-hook).